# Set up telnet server in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, telnet, windows-services

I want to set up a telnet server in windows 8.1 (x64). I tried using "appwiz.cpl" and checking telnet server and telnet client check boxes. Then running "services.MSC" and then changing the telnet startup type to manual. And at last opening cmd as admin and running "net start telnet".
But, when I was trying to start telnet session from Linux client (Ubuntu gnome 16.04) it shows me "failure in initializing the telnet session. Shell process may not have been launched.
Telnet server has closed the connection.
Connection lost by foreign host." So what should I do to start telnet server in windows 8.1 x64.
Note:
1)This is not domain controlled pc, it is a notebook with win 8.1
2) My username contains two words separated by a space e.g. "stack exchange"
Thanks!

Comment: Search for "features" in the Windows search, launch "Add optional features" (or similar), scroll down to "Telnet" and enable the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user who wants to connect to a Windows Telnet server must be a member of the group `TelnetClients` even if the user is already an administrator.

Add your user to the group in the Computer Management console or use:

```
net localgroup "TelnetClients" username /ADD
```

from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Can't add my username. E.g. Consider my username is stack exchange and if I type: net localgroup " TelnetClients" stack exchange /ADD Then it shows me following error: "there is no such global user or group: exchange". Otherwise it worked in another machine with one word username e.g. "stackoverflow" Thanks!